# What is meant by the term "beeline" in an address (latitude/longitude)?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I am supposed to work on an IT project where I have to return the respective technician's data if it falls in operating radius based on the customer's address who can do craftsman work in their home.

Both technician and customer's addresses are stored as (latitude, longitude) and I have to return the matching technicians considering the ***beeline*** of the address. I do not get what the "beeline" is when considering the latitude/longitude of the address. Tried to google it in this perspective but I could not find the right article.

Comment: A beeline is a vector. It has a direction from one point to another. Supposedly it's straight (though anybody who's observed bees wonders where this came from). If you don't know both the starting point and the direction, you can't do it.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the phrase "making a beeline" alludes to bee flight in one particular case: when the bee is returning directly home after foraging.  It doesn't allude to bee flight in general.

Comment: I don't think I've ever heard "beeline" used outside a context like "make a beeline for the nearest <thing>". It's an instruction for travel, not a distance. Usually the concept you are talking is simply described as "nearest craftsman within a <distance> radius".

Comment: I suggest there can be no general solution to that conundrum, and you need to put the Question back to whomever suggested you consider the beeline…

Comment: Who writes specifications like this !? They want the answers sorted by the standard distance metric between earth coordinates. Unless airline travel is contemplated, Haversine formula should be good enough. WGS84 metrology is much more complicated.

Answer (score 25):

There is an equivalent expression

> **As the crow flies**
> The measurement of distance in a straight line.
> *It's only a mile as the crow flies, but about three miles by this mountain road.*

from [Farlex](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/as+the+crow+flies).

So **beeline** means the absolute "nearest technician" without considering the actual road route. However it is more usually used like [this](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/make+a+beeline+for):

> **make a beeline for**
> To head directly and quickly toward something or some place.

Comment: Perhaps to add that the shortest distance as the crow flies is math, not mapping routes for driving there, which must by definition be longer.

Comment: @Fattie It's not off topic. Someone used an uncommon word in a nonstandard context, and clarification was needed. You could make a case for ELL, but I think it's fine here

Comment: I've seen " (as the) crow-flies distance" used in similar situations.  It's common to not present that to end users - try searching on google maps for a business - you'll get the crow-files/beeline distance as a number of miles/km, but clock for directions and the shortest route it can find will always be longer

Comment: As the bee flies

Answer (score 16):

In your context, and as the distances are unlikely to be large, a beeline is a straight line between any two points, regardless of what lies between those two points:

[image]

The edge of the darker circle is in a beeline from the origin of 25.5 miles. You will note that the real distance to be travelled differs depending upon where the finish point is.

Comment: This is appropriate for local technicians but not for those who are globally distributed. See the @Hotlicks answer.

Comment: It's a useful first step for finding technicians within a specified driving distance, since only those within the circle need to be considered by the (more expensive) travel-distance test.  But that's a tangent that's more suited to [softwareengineering.se]...

Comment: Why does the distance depend on the finish point? It depends on the route taken, the start/end points are the same in both cases.

Answer (score 9):

This is another way of saying [Great Circle](https://eclipse2017.nasa.gov/crow-flies-spherical-planet), the shortest distance between two points.

Comment: Correct. If the technicians are part of a global enterprise, this is the best meaning to use. However, If they are merely local within a few miles or tens of miles, the straight line distance is a good and sufficient approximation to the great circle distance.

Comment: @Anton, while we're nitpicking, the great circle distance *is* the straight line distance (for any reasonable definition of "straight line" on a sphere).

Comment: @emil We are not really nitpicking, just stating generality and a particular case of it. Great circle is not defined as a straight line. It is the unique circle on the globe connecting two points with least connecting distance along the arc between points. On the globe it is a circle, On map projections it often appears curved rather than straight. In the particular case of points close on the globe, it shows as a straight line in map projections. If the customers are global, use the great circles; if they are local, use the straight line. These notions should be included in the answers,

Answer (score 2):

> I have to return the matching technicians considering the beeline of the address

You are probably confused because addresses do not have "beelines"; at least, not as the word is typically used. Without seeing original documents that you almost certainly should not be posting on the internet, it's hard to know whether this is a result of your attempt to summarize, or if the original specification is poorly worded.

It seems plausible, however, that the intention of "beeline" here is as [another answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/592743/216063) notes; that is, the imaginary line representing the "territory" of an imaginary bee which flies at most a particular distance from an imaginary hive. I can't say, however, that I've ever encountered this usage outside of this question.

In any case, the intent is presumably to consider only the straight-line distance between the search origin and the potential result, ignoring that you almost surely cannot take such a trivial route. Also, presumably, ignoring elevation changes, though I suspect there are approximately zero instances where elevation difference would be significant for your problem.

As an aside, note that the set of points, as expressed by their latitude and longitude, whose Pythagorean distance from another such point is a constant value, is not going to be a circle. It may, in fact, be significantly different from a circle. You'll need to either use the [Haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula), or convert candidates to e.g. UTM before performing distance calculations.